# My Pygame game doesn't open, but no error is given

Tags: python, pygame

So I wrote a simple matching the pictures for school, but it doesn't open up and no error is given in IDLE. All I get is:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
>>>
```

I don't really know where to go from this.
I'm very sorry, my game is in Estonian maybe it doesn't matter, but if it does I'll translate the names to English.

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *
bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png")

#Põhi muutujad (k - kast), nii on kergem hiljem muuta viga ainult ühes kohas
kanimkiirus = 6
rida = 5
tulp = 5
ksuurus = 50
kvahe = 15
fps = 35
ekraanilaius = 640
ekraanipikkus = 480
kcolor = (255, 255, 255)

kollane = pygame.image.load("1.png")
punane = pygame.image.load("2.png")
roheline = pygame.image.load("3.png")
sinine = pygame.image.load("4.png")
must = pygame.image.load("5.png")

def baas():
        global baaskell, ekraan #Tegin need muutujad globaalseteks
        pygame.init()
        baaskell = pygame.time.Clock()
        ekraan = pygame.display.set_mode([ekraanilaius, ekraanipikkus])
        ekraan.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Malukas')

        #Need kaks muutujat hoiavad infot hiire asukoha kohta
        hiirx = 0
        hiiry = 0

        baasLaud = looSuvalineLaud()
        avatudKastid = tekitaAvatudKastideInfo(False)

        """Need kaks järgnevat muutujat hoiavad infot kasutaja valikute kohta, kui mängija vajutab esimest korda kastile
        saab esimeneSamm väärtuseks False ja esmineValik võrdub sellega, mis selle kasti all oli, kui oli kollane lind saab
        selle väärtuseks see. Kui mängija vajutab järgmisele kastile saame kontrollida, kas teine valik on võrdne esimese valikuga"""
        esimeneSamm = True
        esimeneValik = None

        alustaManguAnimatsiooni(baasLaud) #Mängu alguses näitab kogu lauda korra mängijale

        while True:
                klikitud = False

                ekraan.blit(bg, (0, 0))
                joonistaLaud(baasLaud, avatudKastid)

                #See tsükkel tegeleb sündmustega
                for sündmus in pygame.event.get():
                        if sündmus.type == QUIT or (sündmus.type == KEYUP and sündmus.key == K_ESCAPE): #Mängu sulgemiseks
                                pygame.quit()
                                sys.exit()
                        if sündmus.type == MOUSEMOTION: #Salvestab infot hiire asukoha kohta
                                hiirx, hiiry == sündmus.pos
                        if sündmus.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP: #
                                hiirx, hiiry = sündmus.pos
                                clicked = True

                kastx, kasty = onKastiPeal(hiirx, hiiry) #Kui hiir liigub üle kasti, siis selle kasti kordinaadid salvestatakse siia
                if kastx != None and kasty != None:
                        #Hiir on järelikult üle kasti

                        if not avatudKastid[kastx][kasty]:
                                raamistaKast(kastx, kasty) #See funktsioon loob raami ümber kasti, kui hiir liigub üle kasti

                        if klikitud and not avatudKastid[kastx][kasty]:
                                #Kasutaja klikkis avamata kastile
                                kastiAvamisAnimatsioon(baasLaud, [(kastx, kasty)], kanimkiirus) #See funktsioon tekitab kasti avamis animatsiooni
                                avatudKastid[kastx][kasty] = True

                                if esimeneSamm:
                                        esimeneValik = (kastx, kasty)
                                        esimeneSamm = False #Seame muutuja esimeneSamm väärtuse False ehk valeks, mis näitab, et mängija teeb oma teist valikut
                                else:
                                        lind1 = leiaLind(baasLaud, esimeneValik[0], esimeneValik[1])
                                        lind2 = leiaLind(baasLaud, kastx, kasty)

                                        if lind1 != lind2: #Katab uuesti kastid kinni, kui linnud ei sobi
                                                time.sleep(0.8)
                                                kastiKatmisAnimatsioon(baasLaud, [(esimeneValik[0], esimeneValik[1]), (kastx, kasty)], kanimkiirus)
                                                avatudKastid[esimeneValik[0]][esimeneValik[1]] = False
                                                avatudKastid[kastx][kasty] = False
                                        elif onVoitnud(avatudKastid): #Kui kõik linnud on omavahel sobitatud
                                                manguVoiduAnimatsioon(baasLaud)
                                                time.sleep(2)

                                                #Alustab mängu uuesti
                                                baasLaud = looSuvalineLaud()
                                                avatudKastid = tekitaAvatudKastideInfo(False)

                                                #Näitab lände korra
                                                joonistaLaud(baasLaud, avatudKastid)
                                                pygame.display.update()
                                                time.sleep(1)

                                                #Mängib algus animatsiooni uuesti
                                                alustaManguAnimatsiooni(baasLaud)
                                        esimeneSamm = True #paneb mängija esimese sammu peale tagasi

                pygame.display.update()
                baaskell.tick(fps)

def kastiVasakTipp(kastx, kasty):
        #Arvutab kastide vahed
        vahex = int((ekraanilaius - (rida * (ksuurus + kvahe))) / 2)
        vahey = int((ekraanipikkus - (tulp * (ksuurus + kvahe))) / 2)

        vasak = kastx * (ksuurus + kvahe) + vahex
        tipp = kasty * (ksuurus + kvahe) + ymargin

        return (left, top)

def kujutaLind(lind, kastx, kasty):
        vasak, tipp = kastiVasakTipp(kastx, kasty)
        if lind == kollane:
                ekraan.blit(kollane, (kastx, kasty))
        elif lind == punane:
                ekraan.blit(punane, (kastx, kasty))
        elif lind == roheline:
                ekraan.blit(roheline, (kastx, kasty))
        elif lind == sinine:
                ekraan.blit(sinine, (kastx, kasty))
        elif lind == must:
                ekraan.blit(must, (kastx, kasty))

def looSuvalineLaud():
        linnud = [kollane, punane, roheline, sinine, must]
        random.shuffle(linnud)
        mituIkooniKasutada = int(rida * tulp / 2)
        linnud = linnud[:mituIkooniKasutada] * 2 #ikoonide paarid

        laud = []
        for x in range(tulp):
                tulpa = []
                for y in range(rida):
                        suvalineIndeks = random.randint(0, len(icons) - 1)
                        tulpa.append(linnud[suvalineIndeks])
                        del linnud[suvalineIndeks]
                laud.append(column)
        return laud

def joonistaKastiKate(laud, b, kate):
        vasak, tipp = kastiVasakTipp(b[0], b[1])
        pygame.draw.rect(ekraan, (vasak, tipp, ksuurus, ksuurus))
        lind = leiaLind(laud, b[0], b[1])
        kujutaLind(lind, b[0], b[1])
        if kate > 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(ekraan, kcolor, (vasak, tipp, kate, ksuurus))

def kastiKatmisAnimatsioon(laud, kastid, kiirus):
        for i in range(0, ksuurus):
                for b in kastid:
                        joonistaKastiKate(laud, b, i)
                pygame.display.update()
                baaskell.tick(FPS)

def kastiAvamisAnimatsioon(laud, kastid, kiirus):
        for i in range(ksuurus, -kiirus - 1, -kiirus):
                for b in kastid:
                        joonistaKastiKate(laud, b, i)
                pygame.display.update()
                baaskell.tick(FPS)

def leiaLind(laud, kastx, kasty):
        return laud[kastx][kasty][0], laud[kastx][kasty][1]

def alustaManguAnimatsiooni(laud):
        valeAvatudKastid = tekitaAvatudKastideInfo(False)
        kastid = []
        for x in range(tulp):
                for y in range(rida):
                        kastid.append((x, y))
        random.shuffle(kastid)

        grupid = jagaGruppidesse(8, kastid)

def jagaGruppidesse(grupiSuurus, list):
        tulemus = []
        for i in range(0, len(list), grupiSuurus):
                tulemus.append(list[i:i+grupiSuurus])
        return result

def onVoitnud(avatud):
        for i in avatud:
                if False in i:
                        return False
        return True
def manguVoiduAnimatsioon(laud):
        global kcolor
        valeAvatudKastid = tekitaAvatudKastideInfo(True)

        for i in range(14):
                kcolor = kcolor
                ekraan.blit(bg)
                joonistaLaud(laud, valeAvatudKastid)
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(0.3)

def tekitaAvatudKastideInfo(vaartus):
        andmed = []
        for c in range(tulp):
                andmed.append([vaartus] * rida)
        return andmed

def joonistaLaud(laud, avatud):
        for kastx in range(tulp):
                for kasty in range(rida):
                        vasak, tipp = kastiVasakTipp(kastx, kasty)
                        if not avatud[kastx][kasty]:
                                pygame.draw.rect(ekraan, kcolor, (vasak, tipp, ksuurus, ksuurus))
                        else:
                                lind = leiaLind(laud, kastx, kasty)
                                kujutaLind(lind, kastx, kasty)

def onKastiPeal(x, y):
        for kastx in range(tulp):
                for kasty in range(rida):
                        vasak, tipp = kastiVasakTipp(kastx, kasty)
                        kastiKuju = pygame.rect(vasak, tipp, ksuurus, ksuurus)
                        if kastiKuju.collidepoint(x,y):
                                return (kastx, kasty)
        return (None, None)

def raamistaKast(kastx, kasty):
        vasak, tipp = kastiVasakTipp(kastx, kasty)
        pygame.draw.rect(ekraan, kcolor, (vasak - 5, tipp - 5, ksuurus + 10, ksuurus + 10), 4)
```

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/sXfXatmw).

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\Documents\Python\Lõputöö\pildid.py", line 232, in <module>
    baas()
  File "C:\Users\John\Documents\Python\Lõputöö\pildid.py", line 34, in baas
    baasLaud = looSuvalineLaud()
  File "C:\Users\John\Documents\Python\Lõputöö\pildid.py", line 139, in looSuvalineLaud
    suvalineIndeks = random.randint(0, len(linnud) - 1)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\random.py", line 214, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\random.py", line 192, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)
```

Comment: So many nested blocks/conditions may be a sign of bad code practice. You should consider this, and maybe instead of wrapping whole chunks of code in an `if`-block, test for a -not- scenario first, if not, continue as normal without having to indent. Also; we read, answer and post questions on stackoverflow, not pastebin.

Comment: You don't seem to call `baas()` anywhere. It looks like your script will set some variables, load some images, and then exit.

Comment: It looks like you have defined all your functions, but you never call the baas() function to run the game.

Comment: @Vasar: It appears that you've had an issue with your code not running at all, you received some help, and now have edited the question with the next error you're receiving. We could spend a long time debugging all this code, one error message at a time. Can you spend some time debugging these error messages, and post a NEW question when you get stuck on a one? In that question, try to limit the code to a single function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to call `baas()` anywhere. It looks like your script will set some variables, load some images, and then exit.

Try adding an `if __name__=="__main__":` to the end of your script where you call `baas()` - that means it will be called if your script is run directly.

Comment: Thank you! Well that was a stupid mistake. Okay now I get the window popping up and just stop responding, but this time I get a error too. I added the error to my original post.

Answer (score 3):

Your program does not have a main section that calls any of the functions you define. All of the code before `baas()` is executed, but that just loads constants. You need to call function that initializes you application.

Edit:

```
random.randint(0, len(linnud) - 1)
```

If `linnud` does not have a value, the expression will evaluate to -1. This is an invalid range.